# Facebook app: Using Flex or JQuery

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, facebook

I am about to start a new project, a facebook app.

There are two alternatives for client-side in my mind.
Write Flex-Facebook app. Or write html with Ajax and Jquery.

So what are your opinion, which do you recommend?
What are the issues about each to take into account?
Advantages, disadvantages, subjective opinion?

Thank you help me decide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML application, while it has to be more carefully written to work in all browsers, has the benefit of working on many more platforms. Flash isn't always stable on Mac or Linux, and it only exists on a few mobile platforms. It's not even supported by iPhone (and never will be) or Android (will be in 2.2). Not to mention that while Flash will (probably) be less used in the future, whereas the new features of HTML and JavaScript will keep becoming more prominent on the web.

So my suggestion is to go for a HTML solution if you feel up for it. If you're not very experienced with rich web apps, but you have worked a lot of Flex, maybe you should go with Flex.

Basically it boils down into how much time you want to spend on the project. I think you will get the best quality in the end if you choose HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

first of all depend on what you are going to do!

if you are going to make a Login/Registration and all other stuff that Facebook Connect for example offer, i think you should point to HTML and facebook REST API (php), of course facebook api have it's own javascript library!

second, depends on how many skills you have in both flex and html, since is more easy to find tutorial and example for the second!

3th you can always plan to make widget in flex and other stuff in html!

hope this make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Flex will spit out Flash app. I am in the middle of thinking Flash being good or bad.

But as facebook app I would go for traditional HTML/CSS/JS,  because I guess you want to cover Apple devices (iphone,ipad), which don't have support for flash and don't plan to do so.